# Is there a better way to chain together functions on streams?

Tags: c++, stream

I have a series of functions that takes a stream as input and writes a transformation to an output stream. Right now the interface looks like this:

```
void phase1(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out);
void phase2(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out);

std::istream data = get_initial_data();
std::stringstream first_result;
phase1(data, first_result);
std::stringstream second_result;
phase2(first_result, second_result);
```

Is there an easier/more natural way to chain these calls without using Boost (sorry)?

Comment: If `phase1` returns a reference to the output stream you could write `phase2(phase1(data, first_result), second_result)`.  Is that what you are after?

Comment: Obvious in hindsight... Yes that's exactly it.

Comment: what do you think would be more natural? There are many ways to do that, which one is easier to use is probably opinion based

Comment: I can think of several, but which one to use depends on what you are ultimately trying to do. At first glance what you have written is very memory inefficient depending on how much data you are moving and what you are doing to it during the move.

Comment: @Richard i am a bit puzzled why you think this is memory inefficient. We only see references to streams being passed around.

Comment: @user463035818 If you chain N of these together, N-1 stringstreams are created (in the same scope) and the data is passed from one to the other.  Ideally you'd want the data to be pulled as-needed through a pipeline, so not all of it need exist at the same time.  Imagine a stage that takes a number and turns it into English.  Then a later stage takes an English number and makes it decimal.  If you pass 1 billion numbers through, the above design converts *all billion numbers* to English, then converts them all back.  In an on-demand one, only one number gets converted to English at a time.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d88b654fd5938e7. But yes, as Yakk said, make them into streams themselves, and the entire pipeline becomes MUCH more memory efficient.

Comment: @user463035818 I think Yakk - Adam Nevraumont answered your question for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd want to do:

```
(phase1 | phase2 | phase3)( in, out );
```

where all the glue happens for you.  What more,

```
auto first_part = phase1|phase2;
auto second_part = phase3|phase4;
(first_part | second_part)( in, out );
```

should also work.

```
namespace stream {
  template<class F=std::function<void(std::istream&, std::ostream&)>>
  struct pipe {
    F f;
    void operator()( std::istream& in, std::ostream& out ) const {
      f(in,out);
    }
    template<class O,
      std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same<O, F>{} && std::is_convertible<O, F>{}, bool> = true
    >
    pipe ( pipe <O> o ):
      f(std::move(o.f))
    {}
    pipe (F fin):
      f(std::move(fin))
    {}
  };
  template<class F>
  pipe (F)->pipe <F>;

  template<class First, class Second>
  auto operator|( pipe <First> first, pipe <Second> second )
  {
    return pipe {[=](auto& in, auto& out){
      std::stringstream intermediate;
      first( in, intermediate );
      second( intermediate, out );
    }};
  }
}
```

and now you can do:

```
std::istream data = get_initial_data();
( pipe {phase1} | pipe {phase2} )( data, out );
```

we can extend this to sources and sinks, allowing things to be glued to the input, but that often requires continuation passing style to handle lifetime issues.

You an also use `pipe <>` to handle any stream pipe object in a type-erased manner.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88f9e6778172cf92).

If you want sources and sinks it looks like this:

```
namespace stream {
  template<class Sig, class F=std::function<Sig>>
  struct operation;
  template<class R, class...Unused, class F>
  struct operation<R(Unused...), F>
  {
    F f;
    static_assert(
        std::is_convertible< std::result_of_t< F const&(Unused...) >, R >{}
    );
    template<class...Args>
    R operator()( Args&&...args ) const {
      return static_cast<R>(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
    template<class O,
      std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same<O, F>{} && std::is_convertible<O, F>{}, bool> = true
    >
    operation ( operation<R(Unused...), O> o ):
      f(std::move(o.f))
    {}
    operation (F fin):
      f(std::move(fin))
    {}
  };
  template<class F=std::function<void(std::istream&, std::ostream&)>>
  struct pipe:operation<void(std::istream&, std::ostream&), F> {
    using operation<void(std::istream&, std::ostream&), F>::operation;
  };
  template<class F>
  pipe (F)->pipe <F>;

  template<class First, class Second>
  auto operator|( pipe <First> first, pipe <Second> second )
  {
    return pipe {[=](auto& in, auto& out){
      std::stringstream intermediate;
      first( in, intermediate );
      second( intermediate, out );
    }};
  }

  template<class F=std::function< void(std::function< void(std::ostream&)>) >>
  struct source:operation<void(std::function< void(std::istream&)>), F> {
      using operation<void(std::function< void(std::istream&)>), F>::operation;
  };
  template<class F>
  source(F)->source<F>;
  template<class F=std::function< void(std::function< void(std::ostream&)>) >>
  struct sink:operation<void(std::function< void(std::ostream&)>), F> {
      using operation<void(std::function< void(std::ostream&)>), F>::operation;
  };
  template<class F>
  sink(F)->sink<F>;

  template<class First, class Second>
  auto operator|( source<First> src, pipe<Second> p ) {
      return source{[=]( auto&& f ){
          src([&](auto&& in){
              std::stringstream ss;
              p( in, ss );
              f( ss );
          });
      }};
  }
  template<class First, class Second>
  auto operator|( pipe<First> p, sink<Second> snk ) {
      return sink{[=]( auto&& f ){
          snk([&](auto&& out){
              std::stringstream ss;
              f(ss);
              p(ss, out);
          });
      }};
  }
  void copy_f( std::istream& is, std::ostream& os ) {
      char c;
      while (is.get(c)) {
          os << c;
      }
  }
  inline pipe copy{copy_f};
  template<class First, class Second>
  void operator|( source<First> src, sink<Second> snk ) {
      src([&](auto&& in){
          snk([&](auto&& out){
              copy( in, out );
          });
      });
  }
}
```

you can then do:

```
using namespace stream;
auto src = source{[](auto&& f){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Hello world\n";
    f(ss);
}};
auto snk = sink{[](auto&& f){
    f(std::cout);
}};
src|copy|copy|copy|snk;
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27af78cd2a89fad4)

A `source` is a function object that in turn takes a function object, that it passes an `istream&` to.

A `sink` is a function object that in turn takes a function object, that it passes a `ostream&` to.

This double-function syntax deals with annoying lifetime issues, and lets you do cleanup before/after the client stream-user does stuff with the stream.

And a slightly more insane version that supports direct piping to/from streams is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6eee332f7f9afac).

Comment: I like this default template argument as type erasure, very elegant.

Comment: Instead of making a custom pipe type, why not simply use an operator? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d88b654fd5938e7

Comment: @MooingDuck Operators should be in the namespace of their associated type.  You cannot inject operators into std, and function pointers have no associated namespace.  In the "more insane version" I add ADL koenig operators and the like.  With a touch more work, you could add the ability to *start* with a `namespace stream` element, and the rest of the conversions happen implicitly.  Also yours doesn't support building the pipeline before getting the input/output lined up.